# Why does this std::map not display in a useable way in the watch window of Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, natvis

I'm unable to view certain std::map in the watch window. Looking into the .natvis file, there are multiple implementations for std::map. Is there a way to select one or the other?

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1056550/im-unable-to-inspect-a-variable-of-type-stdmap-in.html

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

typedef std::shared_ptr<std::string> PTR_STRING;
typedef std::map<PTR_STRING, std::size_t> accessFunction2Order;
typedef std::set<accessFunction2Order> setOfAccessFunction2Order;
typedef std::map<std::vector<std::size_t>, setOfAccessFunction2Order> A2B;
typedef std::map<PTR_STRING, std::shared_ptr<A2B> > MAP;

int main()
{   MAP s{
        {    std::make_shared<std::string>("asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"),
            std::make_shared<A2B>()
        }
    };
    const auto &r1 = *s.begin();
}
```

The map s cannot be watched (something regarding std::_Tree<> being displayed). Curiously a reference to the first element can.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with a maximum recursion depth. Are we still dealing with the address space limitations of a 8-bit CPU?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by a (I think hardcoded) limit in the visual studio debugger.
In order to display one variable, the debugger is adapting what he finds in the .natvis file -- but he gives up after some fixed number of attempts to resolve a type.

The solution to this problem is to use something like std::any

(or boost::any for those of us not blessed with being able to use an uptodate C++ version)

to break this STL type into chunks the debugger can deal with.
This is of course only a workaround.
Let's hope that this problem will be solved soon.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <any>
#include <memory>

typedef std::shared_ptr<std::string> PTR_STRING;
typedef std::map<PTR_STRING, long> accessFunction2Order;
typedef std::set<accessFunction2Order> setOfAccessFunction2Order;
#if 1
typedef std::map<std::vector<std::size_t>, std::any> A2B;
#else
typedef std::map<std::vector<std::size_t>, setOfAccessFunction2Order> A2B;
#endif
typedef std::map<PTR_STRING, std::shared_ptr<A2B> > MAP;
typedef std::shared_ptr<std::size_t> PTR_INT;

int main()
{   const MAP s{
        {        std::make_shared<std::string>("asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"), 
             std::make_shared<A2B>()
        }
    };
}
```